# How to combine multiple Unicode character properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

There are `\p{Script=Latin}` (also can be written as `\p{sc=Latin}`) and `\p{Uppercase}`.

But there is currently no way to select an intersection of multiple sets like `/^([ \p{Script=Latin} & \p{Uppercase} ])/` in Perl ≥5.18 or `\p{Script=Latin,Uppercase}`.

So the task is to find a workaround.

Example input:

```js
const input = [
'License: GPL!',
'License: WÐFPL!',
'License: None!',
]
```

Example output: `['GPL', 'WÐFPL']`

The answer could use use a regexp that looks like this for example: `/^License:\s*(?<abbr>\p{Script=Latin,Uppercase}+)!$/u`

Answer (score 2):

There's no ideal workaround to do that except if you want the intersection of predefined character classes. All you have to do is to use a negation and negated character classes:

```
/^License:\s*([^\P{Script=Latin}\P{Uppercase}]+)!/u
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/PVDcRx/1)

It is simple set logic:

```
A ∩ B = ∁∁(A ∩ B)    // complement of a complement is an involution
A ∩ B = ∁(∁A ∪ ∁B)   // Morgan's law: complement of an intersection is the union
                     // of complements
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
'License: GPL!',
'License: WÐFPL!',
'License: None!',
]
const regexp = /^License:\s*(?<abbr>(?:(?![ƗØ])(?=\p{Uppercase})\p{sc=Latin})+)!$/u
console.log(input.map(str => str.match(regexp)?.groups?.abbr).filter(Boolean))
```

Explanation:

```
^
License:
\s*
(?<abbr>   // named capture groups
    (?:
        // A negative look-ahead assertion.
        // Exclusion of Ɨ and Ø was not required by the question;
        // this line is here to provide more examples.
        (?![ƗØ])

        // A look-ahead assertion (looks into the future,
        // and then always goes back to the former position)
        (?=\p{Uppercase})

        \p{sc=Latin}
    )+
)
!
$
```